# How to Git Ignore These Files

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to ignore all of these files that are created w/ Solr/Sunspot.

Basically I want to ignore everything inside of `solr/data` which includes a lot of folders, subfolders, and files.

Comment: Does `/solr/data` in your .gitignore file not work? Remember that .gitignore does not apply retroactively—if you've previously told git to track those files (with `git add`), you'll have to remove them from tracking before git will ignore them.

Comment: The thing that all-too-often catches me is that .gitignore needs to be committed with your list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add

```
/solr/data
```

to your `.gitignore`.

Assumed directory layout:

```
.git
.gitignore
solr/data/
other/
folders/
README.txt
...
```

Comment: `/solr/data` would be a better approach as it is anchored to the repository root and does not require a pattern match.

Comment: Not completely -- the trailing `/*` can be removed.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do `/solr/data` or put a `.gitignore` file *inside* solr/data and just put `*`.

Note that you can't ignore things that have already been committed.