# Git - versioning production and development server

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Git Ignore These Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990534/how-to-git-ignore-these-files)

I migrated a website to another hosting via ftp. I want to use a more secure protocol, so I choose git with ssh... I have a local copy of the files versioned by git, but it has different config files, session files, uploaded images, etc.. I want to push the changes of the local copy when I develop the site but leave those config files, etc... untouched on both machines. Another problem, that I have to backup the uploaded images (about 1.5Gb), so I think a simple ignore is not enough for me, but I have no skills in branching. What should I do?

Comment: Just don't track the files you don't want in each commit.

Comment: Are the config files tracked ?

Comment: Okay it's a bit more complicated. I have to develop features but I don't want to click 200 checkbox to unselect the config files when I commit. The other part that I have to make backup from the uploaded images and the database (about 1.5Gb).

Comment: Ok. I read a lot, this can be solved with simple branching easily. I need 3 branches: 1 for the common part, and 2 for the environments. I just need to merge the changes of the common part (which does not contain config files) to the environment branches (which contain config files). By backup I just need to pull from the server to the production environment branch. If there is a build part in the process I can still create 2 other repos for the output, and I can synchronize one of them with the server if I want a backup.

Thanks the help anyways! =]